# I only have one key, but need to extract objects based on rating

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, parsing

Can I get synsets or words using rating even though it's all under one key? I've been trying to extract json objects based on if their rating is less than 1. However, all the syntax online searches based on key. But I only have one key. Can I search by the object attribute instead?

JSON document:

```
"connections": [
        {
            "synset": 5995898,
            "rating": 1.0,
            "words": [
                "monetarism"
            ],
            "examples": []
        },
        {
            "synset": 1558749,
            "rating": 0.6,
            "words": [
                "driven",
                "impelled"
            ],
            "examples": [
                "felt impelled to take a stand against the issue"
            ]
        },
        {
            "synset": 1421122,
            "rating": 0.17204301075268819,
            "words": [
                "plug in",
                "plug into",
                "connect"
            ],
            "examples": [
                "Please plug in the toaster!",
                "Connect the TV so we can watch the football game tonight"
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Yes you can! And if you show some code demonstrating how you currently load and use the JSON document, and the expected result, I could tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you easily can do it with `sorted` and `filter` function, see examples in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.

```py
import json

conns = json.loads(your_json_payload)["connections"]
filtered = [  # Do some filtering
    obj for obj in conns
    if (
        obj["rating"] <= 1 and
        "KeyPhrase" in obj["words"]
    )
]
sorted_by_rating = sorted(filtered, key=lambda x: x["rating"])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keyWordMatcher.py", line 36, in <module>
    sorted_by_rating = sorted(jsonDict, key=attrgetter("rating"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rating'

Comment: For dicts you could simple use their keys in lambda-functions: sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x["rating"])

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. Is it because my ratings field is of type float?

Comment: Nope, it's because you somewhere use a string, but it hasn't the `read` attribute. Probably, it's an error within json.loads execution? What did you do?

Comment: It worked! I outputted it to a json file and the ratings are sorted. Do you mind if I ask how you to extract the json objects with a rating of 1 or less? Or should I post a new question

Comment: There is `filter` for this: filtered = filter(lambda x: x["rating"] <= 1, your_list). So you can combine them together: sorted(filter(lambda x: x["rating"] <= 1, your_list), key=lambda x: x["rating"]). This filtered your_list first, then sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

So basicly you have one big array you can loop over:

```
arr = [
    {
        "synset": 5995898,
        "rating": 1.0,
        "words": [
            "monetarism"
        ],
        "examples": []
    },
    {
        "synset": 1558749,
        "rating": 0.6,
        "words": [
            "driven",
            "impelled"
        ],
        "examples": [
            "felt impelled to take a stand against the issue"
        ]
    },
    {
        "synset": 1421122,
        "rating": 0.17204301075268819,
        "words": [
            "plug in",
            "plug into",
            "connect"
        ],
        "examples": [
            "Please plug in the toaster!",
            "Connect the TV so we can watch the football game tonight"
        ]
    }
]

for item in arr:
    print(item["rating"])
```

Comment: The actual list is much larger than this. Is there a way to simplify turning it into an array to iterate through?